# How to check if a value exists in one of two WordPress database tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have two registration forms, individual-register.php and school-registration.php. Each one saves data in their own distinct tables. Each one creates its own unique user type (individual and school)

On both of the files I am successfully checking if an email address exists in the database and return and error message if it does. However now I need to checkto make sure that the email address at the time of registration doesn't exist in either of the two tables.

It's peculiar because in the first code block(individual-register.php) it is allowing me to register and it doesn't give me any error  at all unless I try with an email addres that I know exists in the table corresponding to that form.
I have something similar in teacher-register.php howeer it doesn't allow me to register anything at all and returns an error message even if I enter an email addres that is completely new. Please see the code:

individual-register.php

```
        $results_match_email = $wpdb->get_row( 'SELECT * FROM wp_register where artistemail="'.$_REQUEST['artistemail'].'"');
  $check_school_email=$wpdb->get_row( 'SELECT * FROM wp_register_teacher where schoolemail="'.$_REQUEST['schoolemail'].'"');


    if(count($results_match_email) || count($check_school_email) > 0){
      $insert_save=0;
    }


    else{
        $insert_save=$wpdb->insert("wp_register",$insert_reg);
        $lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;
    }
```

teacher-register.php

```
    $results_match_email = $wpdb->get_row( 'SELECT * FROM wp_register_teacher where schoolemail="'.$_REQUEST['schoolemail'].'"');

       $check_individual_email=$wpdb->get_row( 'SELECT * FROM wp_register where artistemail="'.$_REQUEST['artistemail'].'"'); 


       if(count($results_match_email) > 0){

  $insert_save=0;

       }
       else
       {
          $insert_save=$wpdb->insert("wp_register_teacher",$insert_reg); 
          $lastid_teacher = $wpdb->insert_id; 
       }
```

Comment: If possible consider changing this such that there is one table with a field indicating if the entry is a teacher/individual. This is the way its usually done and removes issues like this.

Comment: Honestly my knowledge and experience is very limited. I would prefer to try and make this code work correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Select count(*) as availableemailcount from wp_register, wp_register_teacher where wp_register.artistemail='a@a.com' or wp_register_teacher.schoolemail='a@a.com'
```

Running this query will ouptut the count. If count is greater than 0 the email exists else not.

Comment: What would "availableemailcount" be in my code? Should I assign it to a variable?

Comment: Available email count is the total count of the existing users with the specified email for example(a@a.com) in both your tables. Assign that value in a variable and then put the if-else conditions.. Hope this works for you!

Comment: So i tried it.....didn't work
        $results_match_email = $wpdb->get_row('Select count(*) as availableemailcount from wp_register, wp_register_teacher where wp_register.artistemail="'.$_REQUEST['artistemail'].'" or wp_register_teacher.schoolemail="'.$_REQUEST['schoolemail'].'"');

    if(count($results_match_email) >0){
       $insert_save=0;
     }

It told me that the email address already existed even if it didn't